# Is Django suited to simple webapps?

Tags: python, django

I'm diving into Django to create a webapp.
The thing is, I'm not sure if my app is too simple for what Django offers.

My app will download the latest CPI figures and convert your (monetary) dataset into inflation-adjusted figures, going way back in decades. The user pastes their data in via a textbox. It certainly won't need SQL.

I may want to expand the project with more features in future.

Is it advisable to go with a more lightweight framework for something as simple as I've described?

Comment: Flask is a common light-weight alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every framework has its pros and cons. There are many different frameworks. Personally I prefer Flask but it is all personal preference. Here are some articles that help describe the differences:

- https://www.airpair.com/python/posts/django-flask-pyramid
- https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/1yr8v5/django_vs_flask/
- https://www.hakkalabs.co/articles/django-and-flask

Comment: Seems Flask is good for small projects. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A webapp like the one you describe sounds like most of the work can happen on the client side, without sending the data back to server. From what it sounds like, you simply need to make a few calculations and present the data in a new way.

For this I don't recommend Django, which is ideal for serving pages and managing relational DB content, but not really useful for client side work.

I'd recommend [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/)

Comment: Yes, I considered something in JS but am wanting to learn how Python works on the web. Thanks